# MD4 RFC1320 giving wrong hashes

Tags: c, hash, cryptography

I was trying to get my own implementation of the MD4 hash working, for the Matasano problems, and could not get the correct test vectors. I assumed I was messing up the endianness or something or other at some point.

To figure out where I was going wrong, I decided to compile the reference implementation given in [RFC1320](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1320), go through both programs with a debugger and play "spot the difference." I copy/pasted that code, with no modifications, and ran it with -x (the "test suite" option).

I got the wrong test vectors.

Specifically, the output I got was

```
MD4 test suite:
MD4 ("") = 3e8ce4256176cc6f23583a774a91316c
MD4 ("a") = 40b4c066caa949d3e0576277d2d310df
MD4 ("abc") = a013c51eca433daca5b2a594d21af1fe
MD4 ("message digest") = 40de4367b3e76cee4dc5d90372ced0cf
MD4 ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") = d9b9fc5aa9bfcbefac96214ae64ede8b
MD4 ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789") = 44e0908e086752b6c2b8738212ce278f
MD4 ("12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890") = d219055e9ccff0c40caa7efcef86e10f
```

which, if you compare to the test vectors on [RFC1320](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1320) (or on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD4#MD4_test_vectors)), are totally incorrect.

I then did the same thing with another implementation of the md4 hash which I found online ([this one](http://openwall.info/wiki/people/solar/software/public-domain-source-code/md4)), and got *the same erroneous test vectors*.

How do I begin to figure out where the error is? Am I including some incorrect standard library? Is my processor architecture wrong? Googling the incorrect hashes gives me zero results, so I have to conclude I'm the only idiot who has ever had this problem.

Really appreciate any suggestions on where to start looking.

Comment: OK, I compiled both C source codes (from RFC 1320 and from link http://openwall.info/wiki/people/solar/software/public-domain-source-code/md4) and both .exe files produce correct output on my PC.

Comment: A few ideas: 1. check that `#define MD 4`, `#define MD_CTX MD4_CTX`, `#define MDInit MD4Init`, `#define MDUpdate MD4Update`, `#define MDFinal MD4Final` in mddriver.c. 2. check that you call `MD4_Init(ctx);` before computing hash in the second source code (the struct `MD4_CTX` could initially contain some unpredictable data if you call `malloc` instead of `calloc`)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. Yes, I'm using all of the MD4 functions and not any others. However, what's this about malloc vs calloc? The `typedef struct MD4_CTX` is has fields initialized as arrays, i.e. `UINT4 state[4];` and when testing, a context is simply initialized: `MD4_CTX context;`. Then of course, Init, Update and Final are called in that order. Is it possible that initializing variables as arrays instead of using `malloc` or `calloc` creates issues with passing local variables?

Comment: What OS do you use? 32bit, or 64bit?

Comment: running in a x86_64 Ubuntu build in Virtualbox on a 64 bit Windows.

Comment: ...and `UINT4` etc. are typedef'd to be unsigned longs, which are 64 bits on my processor. I'm going to try changing this and see if it works...

Comment: That was the problem. Changing `typedef unsigned long int UINT4;` to `typedef uint32_t UINT4;` (and likewise to `uint16_t` for `UINT2`) fixed everything. Thank you for your help and for asking the obvious question for me!!

Comment: Great, post it as an answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: @vojta It was posted :)

Comment: Hint: `UINT4` is a horrible name for a variable, make names  indicate what they hold, not their type. `typedef uint32_t UINT4` is also bad because if `uint32_t` is used others will know what it is, `UINT4` is unclear and confusing. Writing good code is all about clarity and understandability for other developer, you never want the next developer to have a WTF moment.

Comment: UINT4 *is* a type, not a variable. And, to be clear, in my own code I would never create a type called UINT4 which is actually just a uint32_t, but I'm modifying legacy code to work properly on my computer for the sole purpose of testing my own code. I appreciate that you're trying to be helpful, but I don't think you read the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from @vojta, I figured out that the problem was in `global.h`, where `typedef unsigned long int UINT4` needed to be changed to `typedef uint32_t UINT4`. On my machine, an unsigned long int is a 64-bit entity, and that was messing everything up.

(Of course, `UINT2` also needs to be typedef'd to `uint16_t`).